# Debug proving something isn't null but issue still occurs [Minecraft]

Tags: java, null, minecraft

I am trying to make my plugin monitor kills and hp of a player but I am currently getting issues with both health and kills with the same error.
I have even tried using null selection to check if it is null and not use it but that wouldn't work as I need the information to show.
I basically need to set the players hp and name as the scoreboard and the kills as the score. (Thank you in advance).
This sets the players kills when joining:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerLogin(PlayerJoinEvent e) {

    String player = e.getPlayer().getName();
                        if(!PlayerHandler.GPlayed.containsKey(player)){
                            PlayerHandler.GPlayed.put(player, 0);
                        }
                        if(!PlayerHandler.kills.containsKey(player)){
                            PlayerHandler.kills.put(player, 0);
                        }
                        if(!PlayerHandler.HRound.containsKey(player)){
                            PlayerHandler.HRound.put(player, 0);
                        }

}
```

And here is a debug I tried creating but the same error still shoots with the relevant checks all being correct.

```
   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void run(String arena){
    for(String key : Handler.playerMap.keySet()){
        if (Handler.playerMap.get(key).contains(arena)){
            Player pt = Bukkit.getPlayer("Nubzz");
            String p = pt.getDisplayName();
            Player nubzz = Bukkit.getPlayer("Nubzz");
            nubzz.sendMessage(key);
            nubzz.sendMessage(pt + "");
            nubzz.sendMessage(p);
            ScoreboardManager manager = Bukkit.getScoreboardManager();
            Scoreboard board = manager.getNewScoreboard();
            Objective objective = board.registerNewObjective("test", "dummy");
            objective.setDisplaySlot(DisplaySlot.SIDEBAR);
            objective.setDisplayName(ChatColor.AQUA + "Wave: " );
            Score score = objective.getScore(ChatColor.GREEN + "" + pt.getHealth() + ChatColor.WHITE + p + ChatColor.AQUA);
            int kills = PlayerHandler.kills.get(p);
            score.setScore(kills);
            int pcheck = 0;
```

This shows the debug working and showing the player has kills (Maybe I'm checking the wrong variables values):
https://gyazo.com/35a83b11a1fb384789a15ae54116248d

Comment: Where is the error occurring? What is the stacktrace?

Comment: You know that if `kills.get(p)` is `null` you also get a NPE?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/87523335d8ab16d403b6c399544d66cb
Sorry for the late reply @forgivenson